# JSF 2.1 + RichFaces 4 - Change rich:dataScroller default stylesheet

Tags: java, css, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I have the page which has the following tags:

```
<h:head>
 <h:outputStylesheet name="style.css" library="css" />
 </h:head>
```

and some kind of dataScroller:

```
<rich:dataScroller for="productsList" id="scroller" maxPages="10">
```

Now I'm trying to override dataScroller default css style by adding

```
.rf-ds { background: black; }
```

in my style.css file.

I don't see any changes. When I open firebug I see both .rf-ds classes one is coming from my css and is disabled and second one is default dataScroller class.

How can I override default class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add !important to your css like this:

.rf-ds { background: black !important; }

see
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-important-css/

Answer (score 0):

Try `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/style.css" />` in your `<head></head>`
.From what I have seen, RichFaces loads CSS attached with `<link>` after it has loaded *its own* CSS, giving *your* CSS precedence.
In our project we needed to customize a lot of components's css and IMHO adding `!important` is not such an elegant solution (its more like a hack). Hence we took this approach.